# How to handle CompletableFuture Threads in loops

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am trying to call an asynchronous thread within a loop. It should break after one iteration mostly that's why I used only one CompletableFuture instance. I am worried about the other case when the loop goes in next iteration. What happens then?

The code goes like this.

```
List<Long> Value = newArrayList();
CompletableFuture<String> future = null;
Boolean done = true;
while(done) {

 future = completableFunction();
 /**
  * Some code here
  *
  */
  Value = someFunction();
  if(!value.isEmtpy()) {
    done = false;
  }
} 

String ans = future.get();
```

The defination of `completableFunction` goes like this

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFunction()
{
  String result;
  /*
   * some code here
   *
   */
   CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
}
```

Can anyone help me will it be problematic if the loop goes into the next iteration? if yes, how possibly can it be handled?

Comment: Why dont you simply move future = completableFunction(); outside the while loop?

Comment: Why are you using a `Future` at all? First, the `completableFunction()` method is not asynchronous, then you're setting the value of `future` in a loop whereas it seems that you only want to create that future once... What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have used loop bcoz in some cases the result might not be computed in a single loop. We need to go to the next iteration to do the same. In such cases I would need the result of last loop executed.

Comment: Anyways, I did some experiment by myself and found that on each iteration, new thread will be executed. The future will always point to the latest thread executed and thus I can get my desired results.